# Searching for a rule engine with fuzzy logic abilities

Tags: rule-engine, fuzzy-logic

I am looking for a rule engine with fuzzy logic abilities. I wanted to use [Jess](http://www.jessrules.com/)

but unfortunately it's fuzzy logic plugin is out of date, it's not supported any more and I was unable to download it anywhere.
Is there any similar modern software with this abilities?
I know about CLIPS and FuzzyCLIPS but seemed to look old and useless nowadays, isn't it?